# Block development: how to bump version on generated css files?

Tags: block-editor

I am building my first Gutenberg custom block, on Wordpress 6.1.1, using the @wordpress/create-block scaffolding.  I have built and deployed my first toy block, and that worked okay.

Now as I am developing, I have made changes to the style files (editor.scss and style.scss), and I can see that the correct css files were generated in the build directory.  However, the plugin is enqueuing these with version 0.1.0, and as a result I'm getting the same toy version of the files that I started with.  I cleared my browser history, but that didn't help, probably because my website is behind a firewall--I am guessing the firewall is caching as well.

I suppose I can go figure out how to tell the firewall to stop it, but it also seems to me that I should be able to bump the version number on the generated css files.  Does anybody know how to do that?   Below is the contents of the top-level plugin PHP file, which as you can see does the enqueuing internally, where I can't get at it:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name:       Cblock
 * Description:       Example block scaffolded with Create Block tool.
 * Requires at least: 6.1
 * Requires PHP:      7.0
 * Version:           0.1.0
 * Author:            The WordPress Contributors
 * License:           GPL-2.0-or-later
 * License URI:       https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 * Text Domain:       cblock
 *
 * @package           create-block
 */

/**
 * Registers the block using the metadata loaded from the `block.json` file.
 * Behind the scenes, it registers also all assets so they can be enqueued
 * through the block editor in the corresponding context.
 *
 * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_block_type/
 */
function create_block_cblock_block_init() {
    register_block_type( __DIR__ . '/build' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_block_cblock_block_init' );
```

Comment: If you’ve made changes to the production build of the stylesheet then that would suggest that you have a new plugin version and that the plugin version should be incremented.

Comment: Sometimes things are very obvious in when they are pointed out :-)   Thank you.

Comment: If you'll make your note an answer, I will accept it.